# how to find documentroot for mod_wsgi django

Tags: django, mod-wsgi

I'm using mod_wsgi/apache2/django for deployment.  In my virtualhost file i don't set a documentroot.  I want to add a symbolic link to the django admin media files.  Is the default documentroot where my settings.py file is located? thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using WSGIScriptAlias then DocumentRoot is irrelevant as WSGIScriptAlias overrides static file handling out of DocumentRoot.

For how to host static files for Django with mod_wsgi see the Django integration guide on the official mod_wsgi site.

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithDjango

Also watch:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/WhereToGetHelp?tm=6#Conference_Presentations

which also goes through Django setup, including static media.